# Best placement for Power Supply Unit in a full ATX case?

Tags: power-supply, power, cooling, computer-building

I've read a few dozen tech articles about Power Supply Units and which may be best for inside a PC case, whether if it's sucking fresh air in, or blowing hot air out to keep it cool. But thing is that hot air rises, so it puts me to asking this question in particular, and what kind of PC cases I should be looking for to best suit for maximum efficient cooling as possible for the PSU for the rest of the components inside it.

The question is; What is the best placement to put the PSU? would it be better if it's at the top of the case or the bottom of the case? and I'm talking for PC cases that are full tower ATX cases that can stand up. I've been trying to look around for a decent full tower ATX case where it lets you choose where to put the PSU. would it really matter that much if the PSU sits on the bottom or at the top at all? My most likely guess is that if it's sitting on the bottom the heat will rise from the PSU if it sat at the bottom of the case, and causing everything else to heat up more inside the case.

I guess this question is basically asking, What kind of full tower ATX case and PSU would be beneficial for maximum cooling efficiency that minimizes heat. I've looked at open full tower ATX cases, but I can see already a downside to that, because dust will collect more easily on everything inside it since it's more openly vented and everythings more exposed, this just makes me really unsure what kind of case I SHOULD be looking for when it comes to PC building. I'm trying to put together ideas for a future gaming PC build that would work best, that has plenty room as well as efficient cooling.

Comment: You usually put the PSU wherever there is the suitable outlet for it in the case. Otherwise you already got the idea and the impact is probably going to be minor so choose whatever looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the power supply generates a fair bit of heat, putting it at or at least towards the top seems most sensible and all of the towers I've seen in years do this.

On the other hand, they weigh a fair bit so putting them in the bottom would be more stable.

I've always had them at or near the top for years.

And the fans on the PSU must blow OUT not suck in. There are several reasons for that: you don't want the heat from the PSU going into the case and you don't want dust from outside being drawn through the PSU.

You want to get a case that allows large fans which can then run slower (therefore quieter), some kind of fabric or foam filtering can be useful if you are in a dusty environment but you should aim to vacuum the vents regularly to maintain maximum cooling - my son is currently doing his gaming tower PC about monthly. If you can, vacuuming internally once every 6-12 months will keep the insides clear too.

Generally, fans run front to back so sucking in at the front and blowing out at the back. A fairly common error is to have front and back fans either both blowing in or both out.

Comment: hmm that's interesting, another fact is that you wont know which way a PSU's fan will be blowing, and it's not like you can just open up the PSU and reverse the fan that should be blowing outwards. Most PSU's I see today are dual fanned, which is the top with a larger fan with a metal grill frame, and the side of them with slightly smaller one.

Comment: You will find that they all flow from the inside to the outside though. The instructions will tell you which way up to mount it.